# Nest.js add global jwt service

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs

I would like to add my jwt service as global service. But its not work in CanActivate(my guard). More precisely, he comes there, but does not have a secret key

This is my code:
Register service as global

```
forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
{
  ...JwtModule.registerAsync({
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
      secret: configService.get<string>('PRIVATE_KEY'),
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '24h',
      },
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService],
  }),
  global: true,
},
```

My Jwt

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {}

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    try {
      const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
      const [bearer, token] = authHeader.split(' ');

      if (bearer.toLowerCase() !== 'bearer' || !token)
        throw new UnauthorizedException({
          message: 'Пользователь не авторизован',
        });
      const user = this.jwtService.verify(token);
      req.user = user;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      throw new UnauthorizedException({
        message: 'Пользователь не авторизован',
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My auth module

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [JwtService],
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UsersModule)],
  exports: [],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Are you using `JwtModule` and `JwtService` from `@nestjs/jwt` or is this a custom approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I use @nestjs/jwt

Answer (score 1):

To take `@nestjs/jwt`'s `JwtModule` and make it global, you need to add it to a global wrapper module and export the `JwtModule` in that wrapper. Something like this:

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get<string>('PRIVATE_KEY'),
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: '24h',
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  exports: [JwtModule]
})
export class GlobalJwtModule {}
```

Now as long as `GlobalJwtModule` is added to your `AppModule` the `JwtService` will be globally injectable

Comment: I use this code for global module
`@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    RolesModule,
    AuthModule,
    //init jwt module
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtModule],
})`

And i try to get from controller
`@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [JwtService],
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UsersModule)],
  exports: [],
})`
`constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {}`

Comment: Don't add `JwtService` to the `providers` array. That tells Nest to make a new instance of it rather than re-use the one in the global space

Comment: And how in that case to be? I created it in app.module and set it as global. And gave the opportunity to export it. And now I need to send the service to import? Then he scolds. If we send jwtModule it is still created without a key. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I would also avoid setting `AppModule` as global (if that's what I understood you did) as that can lead to implicit circular dependencies which are hard to debug. So long as your `GlobalJwtModule` (or similar) is set as `@Global()` and is imported into your root module (e.g. `AppModule`) then whatever your global module exports will be available to the entire application, no need to add `JwtModule` or `JwtService` to any other `imports` or `providers` arrays

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't provided Strategies to `AuthModule` it will not trigger CanActive implementation.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get<string>('PRIVATE_KEY'),
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: '1d',
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy], <=== important here!!
  exports: [AuthService],
})
```

Moreover, if you want to use the Jwt App Guard as global you might need to provide it to `AppModule` in `app.module.ts` like this.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this issue, but I don't understand why.

I imported the jwt module in the auth module

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    global: true,
    secret: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
  }),
}),
```

If I use @UseGuards(AuthGuard) in auth controller there is no problem, but when I use it in other modules, an error will be reported.

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.
```

I have to do this if I want to fix this

```
providers: [<...>, JwtService],
```

But if I don't use registerAsync everything is fine

```
JwtModule.register({
  global: true,
  secret: 'MyJwtSecret',
  signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
}),
```

But in order to use configService I have to use registerAsync.